# why my container isn't fit to 100%?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OktAF.jpg)

here's my codes.

```
<header class="top-nav">
   <div class="container">
      ....
   </div>
</header>
```

that container has 'width : 720px' , 'padding : 0 15px' and 'margin: 0 9px'.
I think It has right width (768px) on iPad(768px x 1024px), but that isn't to fit my page. How can I solve this?

++ I work on Chrome develope tool.

container => container-fluid isn't work for me :(

after using container-fluid, width=738, padding=0 15px, I think It is right too, but It has same problem

Comment: Share a working snippet code !!

Comment: 100% on width only?

Comment: it has the width you have defined - 720 + 15 + 15 = 750 (padding) - margin does not alter the container size.

Comment: @AdamK. right, 750px ,and 16px margin. Is it right on (768px x 1024px)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

container-fluid will be used for 100 % screen.

```
<header class="top-nav">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      ....
   </div>
</header>
```

if its not work, then try like this, and add styles like below

```
.newclassname { 
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Lets try this,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
...
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It is same :( . It dosen't work for me

Comment: Try to add this line <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

Comment: same. can't see right side too.

Comment: I think you need to have padding:0px; try this and check if its okay for you

Comment: same, after changing top-nav to navbar same too.

Comment: solved :) Thank you , have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class container-fluid instead. Example code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootflat</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: please check edited things

Comment: Okay. Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container. Could you place the container-fluid div on the outside instead

Answer (score 0):

Please try class="container-fluid".

Comment: please check edited

Comment: okay then i think try 

.top-nav {width:100%}

and use class="container-fluid"

Answer (score 0):

Manually you can set container width in style.css page like .container{width:1180px;}